# Hash to JSON then joining with another JSON in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have a JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "Low": 8.63,
    "Volume": 14211900,
    "Date": "2012-10-26",
    "High": 8.79,
    "Close": 8.65,
    "Adj Close": 8.65,
    "Open": 8.7
  },
  {
    "Low": 8.65,
    "Volume": 12167500,
    "Date": "2012-10-25",
    "High": 8.81,
    "Close": 8.73,
    "Adj Close": 8.73,
    "Open": 8.76
  },
  {
    "Low": 8.68,
    "Volume": 20239700,
    "Date": "2012-10-24",
    "High": 8.92,
    "Close": 8.7,
    "Adj Close": 8.7,
    "Open": 8.85
  }
]
```

And have calculated a simple moving average for each day of the closing prices and called it a variable `sma9day`.  I'd like to join the moving average values with the original JSON, so I get something like this for each day:

```
  {
   "Low": 8.68,
   "Volume": 20239700,
   "Date": "2012-10-24",
   "High": 8.92,
   "Close": 8.7,
   "Adj Close": 8.7,
   "Open": 8.85,
   "SMA9": 8.92
  }
```

With the sma9day variable I did this:

```
h = { "SMA9" => sma9day }
sma9json = h.to_json
puts sma9json
```

which outputs this:

```
{"SMA9":[8.92,8.93,8.93]}
```

How do I put it in a compatible format with the JSON and join the two?  I'll need to "match/join" from the top down, as the last 8 records in the JSON will not have 9 day moving average values (in these cases I'd still like the key to be there (SMA9), but have nil or zero as the value.

Thank you.

## LATEST UPDATE:

I now have this, which gets me very close, however it returns the entire string in the SMA9 field in the JSON...

```
require json
require simple_statistics

json = File.read("test.json")
quotes = JSON.parse(json)

# Calculations
def sma9day(quotes, i)
close = quotes.collect {|quote| quote['Close']}
sma9day = close.each_cons(9).collect {|close| close.mean}
end

quotes = quotes.each_with_index do |day, i|
  day['SMA9'] = sma9day(quotes, i)
end

p quotes[0]

 => {"Low"=>8.63, "Volume"=>14211900, "Date"=>"2012-10-26", "High"=>8.79, "Close"=>8.65, "Adj Close"=>8.65, "Open"=>8.7, "SMA9"=>[8.922222222222222, 8.93888888888889, 8.934444444444445, 8.94222222222222, 8.934444444444445, 8.937777777777777, 8.95, 8.936666666666667, 8.924444444444443, 8.906666666666666, 8.912222222222221, 8.936666666666666, 8.946666666666665, 8.977777777777778, 8.95111111111111, 8.92, 8.916666666666666]}
```

When I try to do sma9day.round(2) before the end of the calculations, it gives a method error (presumably because of the array?), and when I did sma9day[0].round(2), it does correctly round, but every record has the same SMA of course.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably to do the calculation in ruby, you somehow parsed the json, and got a ruby Hash out of it.

To get this straight, you have an array of sma9day values, and an array of objects, and you want to iterate through them.

To do that, something like this should get you started:

```
hashes = JSON.parse( json )
sma9day_values = [9.83, 9.82, etc... ]

hashes.each_with_index do |hash, index|
  if index >= 9
    hash["SMA9"] = sma9day_values[index-9]
  else
    hash["SMA9"] = 0
  end
end

puts hashes.to_json
```

Edit:

You really need to try a beginning ruby tutorial. The problem is that you are calling round(2) on an array. The variable i in the `sma9day(quotes, i)` function is not used (hint). Maybe try something like `sma9day[i].round(2)`

Also the return of each_with_index is not something to assign. Dont do that, just call each_with_index on an array. I.e.

```
quotes = quotes.each_with_index do |day, i| #bad
quotes.each_with_index do |day, i| #good
```

Comment: Hi AJ, I thought I commented on this, sorry for not replying sooner.  I played with your code yesterday, but couldn't get it to work for me.  Then Thomas posted and I've been playing with that trying to figure it out.  Thanks for your help (again)!

Comment: Hi AJ - sorry for the late reply - as you suggested, I did some (more) ruby tutorials and I'm happy to say that everything is working!  I kept having problems with the rounding, and then realized it was because of the nil values at the end of the json (trying to round nil).  So I added an if statement to only round if the value was not nil.  Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I took your input and compiled a solution in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3979626). I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas.  I had a little problem because I calculated my average a little differently, would you mind looking at Update #2 above and letting me know what you think?  Thanks again for your help.  PS:  I noticed you did a sma9.round(3) to get a figure with three integers?  Is there a way to force two decimal places (if I didn't know how many digits would be in front of the decimal, but wanted to make sure there were two decimal places?).

Comment: Here's what the simple_statistics gem does: [source code](https://github.com/craigmdavidson/Simple-Statistics/blob/master/lib/simple_statistics.rb). There are many other ways you can calculate the unweighted average with the same results, one shown in the gist.

Comment: Yes, but I am also using the weighted average, as such using the gem is easiest.  Thanks for your help though